# google-analytics-api Create a Google Analytics account for each client

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am a development engineer of Alibaba。
We are doing a service similar to shopify。
Now I want to create a GA account for our customers to associate their own Google account。

I know that GA accounts can be created through the following two apis

POST https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/accounts:provisionAccountTicket

https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?provisioningSignup=false#/termsofservice/K9xxj2CjQwC8zHVA2vLteA

But I don't know how to connect the customer's Google account。

Or specify the customer's own Google account when creating the GA account。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run [accounts.provisionAccountTicket](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/accounts/provisionAccountTicket) your code must first be authorized, by the user who you would like to create the account for.  This is done via oauth2.

Once the user has then clicked the consent to create the account, the user is the owner of the account.

Comment: hello，Can the user complete the authorization only by accessing the authorization page through the browser?  and can I use the API to implement the authorization process?

Comment: The oauth2 consent screen is browser based yes